# Negative Moments Sufficiency

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I'm reading a paper in which the authors want to prove something like this:

> \begin{align}\tag{1} E(X^{-p})< \infty, \end{align} where $p \geq 2$ and $X$ is a nonnegative random variable.

They say it's enough to show the following:

> Fix $a \in (1/2,1)$. Then, for all $p \geq 2$, there exists a $c_0$ (depending on $p$ and $a$) such that if $c \leq c_0$, then \begin{align}\tag{2} P(X\leq c^a) \leq c^{(1-a)p}.  \end{align}

I am trying to prove that this is indeed sufficient for $X$ to have negative moments (i.e $(2)\implies (1)$). My attempt:

1. Use integral representation of expectation, split the integral at $c_0^{-ap}$, and bound the first term by a constant.

\begin{align}
E(X^{-p}) &= \int_0^{\infty} P(X^{-p}>y) dy \\
&\leq c_0^{-ap} + \int_{c_0^{-ap}}^{\infty} P(X<y^{-1/p})dy
\end{align}

2. Change variables: $ y= c^{-ap} $, so $dy = -apc^{-ap-1}dc$, and
   $$
   \int_{c_0^{-ap}}^{\infty} P(X<y^{-1/p})dy = ap \int_0^{c_0} P(X < c^a)c^{-ap-1}dc.
   $$
3. Use the assumed (2) to get
   $$
   \int_0^{c_0} P(X < c^a)c^{-ap-1}dc 
   \leq \int_0^{c_0} c^{(1-a)p}c^{-ap-1}dc 
   = \int_0^{c_0} c^{p(1-2a)-1}dc.
   $$

The issue here is that the exponent of $c$ is in the interval $(-2,-1)$, which makes the integral diverge. The authors say that $(2)\implies (1)$ is "clearly" true, so there's probably something "simple" that is not occurring to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the authors meant $a\in(0,1/2)$. Later in the paper, did they actually use an $a\in(1/2,1)$?

Comment: Ah, I think you may be right. At some point, the authors pick $c_0$ small enough so that $\sqrt{c} \geq c^a$ (up to some multiplicative constants) for $c \leq c_0$, which isn't true if $a<1/2$. It is, however, possible to pick such a $c_0$ when $a > 1/2$. Does this sound correct to you, @AlexR.?

Comment: Could you link the paper and the relevant page number?

Comment: @AlexR. - I couldn't track down a digital copy of the paper, but I requested one from my university's library (they tend to have a pretty quick turn around with this process).

Comment: @AlexR. - I obtained a pdf of the paper. How should I share this with you? I'm not seeing a way to attach a file to a comment/post here.

Comment: Oops! I noticed an error in my comment: $\sqrt{c} \geq c^a$ for $c$ small  only when $a > 1/2$. So, $a \in (1/2,1)$ is consistent with $\sqrt{c} \geq c^a$ for $c$ small, which is the issue I started with.